# Wincdemu and windows explorer can no longer read a lot of iso files

Tags: iso-image

The iso files used to work. I back up all of my cd using iso files. Now I cannot open them. Windows say it's corrupted. But I don't think so many iso files can be corrupt at the same time

Is there any other way to check if an iso file is corrupt or not.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your CD drive? Something like https://www.amazon.co.uk/DVD-Lens-Cleaner-Compact-Disc/dp/B0021Y57PQ should be suitable.

Comment: several different iso files no longer works. In fact most of them. It's as if they were in some old format and now they're missing something

Answer (score 0):

I believe, from multiple experiences of CDEmu making usable and readable .isos, but then literally 5m later, some incomplete process ... some kind of registry or something?

not being done, the legitimate, worked at-first ... <5m or so ,  .iso , then has glitches, and something CHANGES within a very small time-frame.

For me, the first 5 DVDs of a series i purchsed 2nd hand through Ebay,
which as-far-as-I-know, was a legitimate RE-purchase, a TRANSFER of ownership
(& liscence to view/own / make a back-up of in case of destroying your original) ,
worked ... but then ANY further ones with a similar name, or perhaps something in-common in the data on the disc that the program recognised was still in the same series , of the same product ... *shrugs* ... not sure ... but SOMEthing,

then became corrupted after a time-frame was passed,
after at-first working, after being written.

( EACH time, this is,  a-pattern-of-a-DELAY )

SO literally, i would RE-attempt disc 6,
it would finish, no-bad sectors,

then i would immediately,  UNDER 5m , mount it while still in my HHD, and it would WORK, the emulator could mount it...

but then give it a few minutes,

and then simulator-mounting THE SAME .iso,
that had JUST worked, only moments before,

'suddenly'  has glitches.

I felt like doing it to a USB, and then unplugging my computer and rebooting, and trying to mount it and load it without being connected to the net, or CDEmu running WHEN then trying to load it ... and trying to mount it off the USB if neccessarily,..

JUST to see, if it would work,
and therefore if the program, or some kind of hidden DRM content process, is deliberately corrupting my .iso.

!%(!&#^%(!!!!!!!!!!!

I legitimately bought my whole series, the Ghost in the shell series,
2nd hand, including the liscence to use it ... DUH ... that's reasonably-assumed,

and can PROOVE my purchase ... were the companies even slightly caring about the BUYER, rather than their sales-pitch that one technology rather than another is better, to producers and entertainment marketers and distributers, etc...

... but of course they aren't ... and they don't CARE, if you legitimately purchase it or not.

Not only is there no likely no way of finding out,
HONESTLY, from CDEmu, if their program does that, or the same goes for Windows, if it is Windows/Microsoft's ASSUMPTIONS,

but there is presumably even LESS of a likelyhood, of being able to SEND TO THEM, your proof-of-purchase.

---

it is an UNregulated and neglected area of consumer and sales law, that NONE of the big companies are willing to try to address, in fear of everything going downloadable ANYway, and their fears about copying pure-data  -  a fair enough concern,

but products like CDEmu, just make things worse for people who cannot use their legitimate purchasing, receipts, CCard transactions, etc,

to PROOVE, that what the program reacts-to, in DRM,

should NOT BE,

since you are making your legitimate back-up.

---

In other words, they don't even TRY,
to tell the difference,

and then just claim that that's somehow legitimate, because some people would abuse trust if they trusted everyone.

BUT is that what we're asking for ... FROM, progrmas like CDEmu?

I know i'm NOT.

I simply want SOME way, of DRM or similar security, to be able to check RE-purchasing, and 2nd-hand TRASNFERS of rights,

if they have bothered to goto the effort for 1st purchasers, CCard transactions via bank records, etc.

---

If they're not going to, when your TRANSFER of ownership and viewing, and 1-copy rights are LEGITIMATE,

then they are failing in THEIR COMMERCIAL CONDITIONS OF SALE ... to facilitatte a way that you can proove it,

and so then you're pretty much given a green light to illegally burn it with something dodgy.

---

ONLY 1 copy ... and STILL limited to personal use,.. ONLY.

But what else can you do?

They leave re-purchasers with no-option, while maintaining that they're participating in security co-operations, when it comes to 1st-buyers , 1st-purchasers,

while burying their heads in the sand, when it comes to JUST AS legitimate RE-purchasers, of which they need to do something a bit LESS-AUTOMATIC, than CCard transaction checking, or whatever.

THAT said to me, the 1st time i explored this issue ( late 1990s ) ,
that they ONLY REALLY CARED, about those 1st-sales profit,

and had no GENUINE INTENT, to facilitate the same for RE-purchasers, TRANSFER-recipients, to proove, that they now owned the rights.

It was deliberately avoided, and profiteering was the obvious reason.

If you're a RE-purchaser ... a 2nd-hand purchaser, then disregard THEIR rights, because they're stomping all over yours, in trying to get you to buy a new one, when you shouldn't have to.